# Are there infinitely many full reptend primes?

Tags: number-theory

A prime $p$ is said to be full reptend if the period length in the decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{p}$ is $p-1$. Now, I want to know how can some one prove that there are infinitely many full reptend primes. I know this is the artin's conjecture on primitive roots. But, I am having a hard time understanding the conjecture and relating it to the case of full reptend primes.
Kindly explain the conjecture and how it comes into play in case of full reptend primes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know this [reference](https://oeis.org/A001913) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I know about that. But I am not sure how to prove that there are infinitely many full reptend primes.

Comment: What we need is that the given prime has $10$ as a primitive root. There should be infinite many primes doing the job, but the problem is open. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots)

Comment: @Peter So, the problem is **Prove that the number of primes for which $10$ is a primitive root is infinitely many**

Comment: @Peter **If** the above statement is proved then we can say that there are infinitely many full reptend primes. Right ?

Comment: @cabmetric Yes, that's right.